# Distance between a matrix of points, simple if & for's

Tags: r, matrix, geometry, distance

I want to run a function that gives the distance between the two points. I want to calculate the distance between all the points with each other how do I do it. I understand it can be done using `if` or `for`, but I am not great with using these.

My function is:

```
Distance<- function(x,y)    {
  round(sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2)),3)
}
```

I have 34 points in easting and northing or x & y of the above funtion:

```
easting=rbind(609027, 609282, 609501,609497,609405,609704,609718,610277,610530,610573,609875,608947,609865,611105,611169,611243,611388,611598,611339,611310,611212,611150,611358,611626,611763,611887,612043,612134,612160,612539,612857,613062,613154,613303)
northing=rbind(1534293,1534470,1534630,1534848,1534027,1535054,1535315,1535583,1535717,1536254,1536351,1536700,1536746,1536762,1537003,1537261,1537489,1537685,1537838,1538103,1538500,1538812,1539217,1539342,1539627,1539842,1540027,1540357,1540628,1540911,1541623,1541896,1542117,1542494)
```

If `coords<-as.data.frame(easting,northing)` is my dataset, then I want to calculate the distance between `coords[i,]` and `coords[j,]`. where `i`,`j` are the rows in the dataset.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [dist](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/dist.html) function:

```
df  <- data.frame(easting=easting,northing = northing)
dist(df) # or round(dist(df,upper=T,diag=T),3)
```

example for the first three rows:

```
round(dist(df[1:3,], upper=T,diag=T),3)

        1       2       3
1   0.000 310.409 581.588
2 310.409   0.000 271.221
3 581.588 271.221   0.000
```

Comparison:

```
round(dist(df[1:3,]),3)

        1       2
2 310.409        
3 581.588 271.221
```

Comment: This gives me 561 values if I use all 34 rows. I should get 1156.

Comment: From each row, you can measure the distance to 33 other rows. `561 = (34*33)/2`. So that is the total of unique distances. If you use ` `round(dist(df,upper=T,diag=T),3)` instead of `dist(df)`, you will also get the values on the diagonal and the upper triangle. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: You mean rest of the value are omitted? Its the blank I see in the results.

Comment: If you use `dist(df)`, the rest of the values are omitted. If you use `round(dist(df[1:3,], upper=T,diag=T),3)`, the full distance matrix is constructed. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, why are the values slightly different from that of `geosphere::distm` if I use latitude and longitude instead of easting and northing. Could this be projection errors acting?

Comment: Because distm uses [distHaversine](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-5/topics/distHaversine), which uses another distance calculation, because the earth is not a 2D surface. Regular dist assumes points to be on a 2D surface. So yes, I guess that's projection errors.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to change some details of how you create your `data.frame`. Instead of defining the vectors `easting` and `northing` with `cbind`, use `c`. Then use `data.frame`, not `as.data.frame`.

```
easting = c(609027, 609282, 609501,609497,609405,609704,609718,610277,610530,610573,609875,608947,609865,611105,611169,611243,611388,611598,611339,611310,611212,611150,611358,611626,611763,611887,612043,612134,612160,612539,612857,613062,613154,613303)
northing = c(1534293,1534470,1534630,1534848,1534027,1535054,1535315,1535583,1535717,1536254,1536351,1536700,1536746,1536762,1537003,1537261,1537489,1537685,1537838,1538103,1538500,1538812,1539217,1539342,1539627,1539842,1540027,1540357,1540628,1540911,1541623,1541896,1542117,1542494)
coords <- data.frame(easting, northing)
```

Now, in order to use function `apply` you also need to change your function, to have it accept a vector as an argument.

```
Distance<- function(x, y)    {
  round(sqrt(sum((x - y) ^ 2)),3)
}
```

And use a nested `for` loop

```
d <- numeric(34^2)
k <- 0
for(i in seq_len(nrow(coords)))
    for(j in seq_len(nrow(coords))){
        k <- k + 1
        d[k] <- Distance(coords[i, ], coords[j, ])
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just compute 34 distances rather than all 34^2 distances? You could use `expand.grid()` perhaps. In any event -- the columns would contain just individual numbers and not points.

Comment: @JohnColeman OK, now I've seen Florian's answer. I'll edit mine.

Comment: The problem is still that you are in effect computing the absolute value between the  `x` coordinates from some points and `y` coordinates from others as opposed to computing distance between points. `easting` are the x-coordinates and `northing` the y. Calculating the distance between an element of `northing` and an element of `easting` doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Of course using the built-in `dist` would be more efficient, but you are perfectly correct to point out the problems with how OP constructed their data frame.